# Static values are based on the number of classes in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, static, junit5

I am very rusty in java and trying to relearn it again in a youtube tutorial, the code is as follows: This is Person.java

```
package com.gurmeet.javacourse.lesson2;

import com.gurmeet.javacourse.lesson3.Name;

public class Person {

private Name personName;
private static int personCounter;

public Person()
{
    personCounter++;
    /*
     * empty on purpose - default constructor
     */
}

public Person(Name personName) {
    this.personName = personName;
}

public String helloWorld() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "Hello World";
}

public String hello(String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "Hello " + name;
}

public static int numberOfPersons() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return personCounter;
}

}
```

And this is PersonTest.java

```
package com.gurmeet.javacourse.lesson2;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class PersonTest {

@Test
public void shouldReturnHelloWorld() {
    
    
    Person marcus = new Person();   
    assertEquals("Hello World", marcus.helloWorld());
}

@Test
public void shouldReturnHelloMarcus() {
    Person person = new Person();
    assertEquals("Hello Marcus", person.hello("Marcus"));

}

@Test
public void shouldReturnNumberOfPersons() {
    Person person1 = new Person();
    Person person2 = new Person();
    Person person3 = new Person();
    Person person4 = new Person();

    assertEquals(4, Person.numberOfPersons() - 1);

}

}
```

these two above are in the same package but I created another package in the same project like below:

```
package com.gurmeet.javacourse.lesson3;

public class Name {

}
```

I am using JUnit to test my code, but in the for the last testing in my code I keep getting an error, you see the number of persons is supposed to be 4, but the result keeps showing 5. The youtube guy got the correct answer and I didnt even though I followed his coding correctly. What I came to understand in the tutorial is that the static is a global, at class level and since I have two classes created in the same package, the personCounter is not at 1 but 2 at default, therefore the it keeps showing 5 instead of 4. I solved it by subtracting 1 in the method but I dont think that is the correct way. Is my reasoning correct? or is there another explanation. And above all else, how do I solve this? Go easy on me if I made any mistake.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, you don't increment the counter when you call the non-default constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the main problem is that when you run the first two tests, the static variable personCounter becomes 2 as you are creating two objects. Then when you run the third test, it starts from the 3 and goes upto 6.

I guess if you add another method to set the person counter to zero and call this method before creating the objects in the third test, you would get 4 as your output.

Add this in you class as a function

`public static void setNumberOfPersons(int value) { personCounter = value; }`

And then call `Person.setNumberOfPersons(0);` first in the third test

Edit:

Thanks to [seelenvirtuose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2563754/seelenvirtuose)(see comment) for pointing out the random order part for tests. As said, I suppose the problem would go away by setting the value to 0 in the third test. This way the order would not matter.

Comment: Although this goes into the right direction, this is no completely true. By default, JUnit runs tests using a deterministic, but unpredictable order (MethodSorters.DEFAULT). This default strategy compares test methods using their hashcodes. It happens that the `shouldReturnNumberOfPersons` runs second - having the number of persons equal to  5.

Comment: and here I thought it was because of the static, im really bad at this haha. How do I reset the value to 0?

Comment: @CodingNeeded This is an excellent example of why static state is a _big problem_. Instead of a `personCounter` that has all these sorts of problems, you should just have a `List<Person>`; you can make as many as you need, and you can just call `size()`.